# image from sql table not following css

Tags: php, css, mysql

For the images for my website I take them from my sql table. The majority of the images are working and style how they are supposed to. However, the image for my header background is not and I cannot figure out why since the other images work fine.

This is the code for the header background which shows how I take the image from my sql table:

```
<header class="background -display-container -grayscale-min" id="home">
        <?php
        try {
        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT image_title, image FROM images WHERE id= 1 ');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<img src='admin/uploads/".$row['image']."'";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
?> 

  <div class="logan-display-left slogan" style="padding:48px">
    <span class="-jumbo -hide-small">Baking for you since '62</span><br>
    <p><a href="#about" class="-button -white -padding-large -large -margin-top -opacity -hover-opacity-off">Learn more</a></p>
  </div> 
</header>
```

This is the css it is supposed to follow:

```
/* Full height image header */
.background {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You're outputting `<img>` tag, but you CSS looks like you're expecting the image to be on background?

Comment: Also you never closed the img tag `"<img src='admin/uploads/".$row['image']."'";` should be `"<img src='admin/uploads/".$row['image']."' />";`

Comment: If the problem is entirely with your CSS then simplify your example.  View the page source in your browser and examine the HTML output.  There's no reason to put so much attention to your server-side code.

Comment: Yeah it is supposed to be on background, what should it be instead of the <img> tag then? And thanks dimitris sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how it should be:

```php
<header class="background -display-container -grayscale-min" id="home" style="background-image: url(
        <?php
        try {
        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT image_title, image FROM images WHERE id= 1 ');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "admin/uploads/".$row['image'];
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
?>">
```

So, instead of producing `<img>` tag, `background-image` CSS attribute is set. Then your `background` class does the rest.

Update. Well, while we're at it, here is a bit better version of the code with image URL fetching functionality extracted into reusable function:

```php
<?php
function imageUrl($id) use ($db)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT image FROM images WHERE id=  ' . (int)$id);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return "admin/uploads/".$row['image'];
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        // This way you at least will see error in your server logs, and probably in browser console:
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
<header class="background -display-container -grayscale-min" id="home" style="background-image: url(<?= imageUrl(1) ?>;">
```

Comment: comes up with an error saying unexpected use expecting { ?

Comment: error goes away if I do $image url = function ($id) use ($db) { etc and then obviously change imageUrl(1) to $imageUrl(1). However I then get an error saying that image wasn't found, it knows what it's looking for but for some reason can't manage

Comment: Well, can't help much with that since I don't have full environment to reproduce. Anyway, that's just a hint re how to make it better code-wise. If it works for you as is, that's great, nothing is *needs* to be changed. BTW, good catch with `use`.

Comment: I'll play about with it and see if I can get it to work because would be quite a useful function to have I think but thanks again for your help, much appreciated